# Selenium Sql Server connection established but shows error of hyphen "-" in table name

Tags: sql-server, selenium-webdriver

Sql connection is established with Selenium but my table name has hyphen "-" in it like; "table-1". So it shows below error. Other tables without hyphen are accessible. Please suggest.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Comment: Did you try using `[]`, i.e : `SELECT * FROM [xyz-123]`

Comment: It worked Thanks!

Comment: ok I posted as answer, please accept if all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use square brackets [] so it will access your table and won't cause issue of `'-'` :

```
SELECT * FROM [xyz-123]
```